# 3D object does not show original colors using obj file in QML

Tags: qml, qt3d

I am trying to show simple 3D car using following QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2 as QQ2
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0

Entity {
    id: sceneRoot

    Camera {
        id: camera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 500.0
        position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, -40.0 )
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
    }

    OrbitCameraController {
        camera: camera
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {
            activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0.5, 1, 1)
                camera: camera
            }
        },
        // Event Source will be set by the Qt3DQuickWindow
        InputSettings { }
    ]
    Mesh{
        id: sphereMesh
        source: "qrc:/../../../../../Desktop/Qt-3d/assets/55z27frcahz4P911GT/Porsche_911_GT2.obj"
    }

    PhongMaterial {
        id : spherematerial
        shininess: 1
    }

    Transform {
        id: sphereTransform
        property real userAngle: 0.0
        scale: sceneRoot.scale
         rotation: fromAxisAndAngle(Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0), 45)
        matrix: {
            var m = Qt.matrix4x4();
            m.rotate(userAngle, Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0));
//            m.translate(Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 20));
            return m;
        }
    }

    QQ2.NumberAnimation {
        target: sphereTransform
        property: "userAngle"
        duration: 10000
        from: 0
        to: 360

        loops: QQ2.Animation.Infinite
        running: true
    }

    Entity {
        id: sphereEntity
        
        components: [ sphereMesh, spherematerial, sphereTransform ]
    }
}
```

However, when exeucuted this code, I can see the 3D car rotating. But it does not contain the original colors from the 3D object. It is showing the default colors for the 3D car. How can I get the original colors?

1. Do I need to use Texture with the material? If Yes, how to do that?
2. Do I need to use mtl file in QML? If yes, how to do that

Note that,

1. I do not want to use Qt Quick 3D module for some reasons.
2. Also, I not want to use Qt3DStudio

Answer (score 1):

Loading a mesh using `Qt3D::QMesh` only loads the vertex data (vertices, normals, texture coordinates) but no textures and it doesn't add any `Qt3DRender::QMaterial`s. You're adding a simple `Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial` which simply applies one color to the whole object.

If your object provides per-vertex-color-information you could try `Qt3DExtras::QPerVertexColorMaterial`.

If it doesn't work try `Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader`: there you set the URL to the model and it loads everything automatically and tries to apply the correct materials. Create it in place of the `QMesh` and also add it as a component.